# Query that displays the data if they have the same data from table 1 to table 2

Tags: mysql, join

My target is to display the first name and last name with the same data on my target output. I have provided a table below for your reference.

**Table 1: tbl_user**

| first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- |
| roger | paul |
| law | marshall |
| steve | fox |
| nina | williams |
| sakura | flower |

**Table 2: tbl_account**

| first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- |
| roger | paul |
| law | marshall |
| steve | fox |
| nina | kicks |
| sakura | hana |

**My target output:**

| first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- |
| roger | paul |
| law | marshall |
| steve | fox |

As we can see on the target output, there is no `"Nina williams"` and `"sakura flower"`. It happens because, on the first table and the second table, their first name and last name didn't match.

Any idea on how I can achieve my target? Thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple inner join should work here:

```sql
SELECT u.first_name, u.last_name
FROM tbl_user u
INNER JOIN tbl_account a
    ON a.first_name = u.first_name AND
       a.last_name = u.last_name;
```

Another way, using a union:

```sql
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM
(
    SELECT first_name, last_name FROM tbl_user
    UNION ALL
    SELECT first_name, last_name FROM tbl_account
) t
GROUP BY first_name, last_name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: I will try these. Thank you. Will keep you updated.

Comment: Perfectly Working. Thank you so much, Tim.